# Trouble deleting features from polygon in QGIS - features do not delete

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing, delete

Apologies if this is a daft question, I have googled it and searched on here, but can't find an answer. I have a multipolygon shapefile of different pockets of woodland. I am trying to delete some of the pockets - I have tried selecting and deleting through the attribute table, I also have tried selecting and deleting using the single-click selector and 'cut features' option (see attached screenshot). The process seems to work and I save the edit, but then find the feature is not deleted. If I re-open the attribute table after deleting from there, the feature is back in place even after saving. The message log gives the following error:

"Unbalanced call to leaveUpdateMode() w.r.t. enterUpdateMode()"

I have searched on this too, but nothing covers my problem. Can anyone advise please?

[image]